# Data is not updating into database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, database

I want to update the values of textboxes into my SQL Server database.

The code does not show any syntax error and redirects easily to the page I'm redirecting but still database is not updating the new data in it.

```
conn.Open();

string str_id = Session["userid"].ToString();

int id = Convert.ToInt32(str_id);
id = Int32.Parse(str_id);

string updatequery = "Update empdata set fname='" + updatename.Text + "',education='" + updateeducation.Text + "',position='" + updateposition.Text + "',email='" + updateemail.Text + "',address='" + updateaddress.Text + "',contact='" + updatecontact.Text + "',account='" + updateaccount.Text + "',postal='" + updatepostal.Text + "',password = '" + updatepwd.Text + "' Where id = '" +id.ToString()+ "'";

SqlCommand updateinfo = new SqlCommand(updatequery, conn);
updateinfo.ExecuteNonQuery();
updateinfo.Dispose();

updationmessage.Text="<p style='color:green;'>Information updated successfully</p>";
```

Comment: https://xkcd.com/327/ thar be sql injection vulnerabilities here!

Comment: If you set a breakpoint at the line after setting updatequery, you can get the actual query that is being attempted.  Also, your code is vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: Are the textboxes initial values being loaded from the database? It might be a PostBack issue

Comment: Can you show the code for insantiating conn?

Comment: is the viewstate enabled in the page?

Comment: What is the datatype for your column `id`?

Comment: Find out where your databse is and how many copies there are.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly,switch to ParameterBinding, your code is prone to sql inection (and slower)

Secondly, check the return value of `ExecuteNonQuery`. If it is 0, then there was no change in the database, meaning no matching id has been found

Thirdly, check if you are within a transaction where you need to commit the transaction - otherwise you will not see anything in the database.